# More rigorous rules for including image samples in the question

Tags: discussion, feature-request, images

I am spending most of my time on Stack Overflow moderating and learning from examples posted with [opencv] and [image-processing] tags. Yet most of the people, who ask questions don't include image samples and instead try to explain the visual with words.

That in 99% of the cases sounds a little bit like saying: "Hi, I'd like to know if the car I have here on the photo is black or white. Could you tell me what color it is?" and not including the photo you're regarding. [Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42996382/how-to-detect-all-lanes-on-a-road-from-multiple-lane-detections-on-multiple-car). It could be an interesting case to solve if the images were included in the question.

I think that Stack Overflow's [image-processing] questions would greatly benefit from some kind of mechanism that puts more pressure on people to include sample images in their questions. I am not sure if that's a communication issue (maybe we could communicate that after somebody chooses the tag or something) or how exactly to solve that but it is a huge pain in the ass for me, trying to use and moderate those questions.

I'm not sure if that issue extends to any other tags but I can imagine a similar problem when someone wants to process numerical data and doesn't include any samples of the data itself or something. I know that we can't treat new users as 5 yo and hold their hands every step of the way but I think we could all benefit from clearer, well-communicated tips like that.

Comment: Do we really need a new feature?  Can't we just close the question if they lack what is needed?  In your example post for instance, that question is way too broad.  All we need to do is close that.

Comment: Sure we could but is that a better way? That's just one example of - I think - a broader issue. People just can't put themselves in the shoes of the people who they are explaining their issue to. There are many other, more detailed questions, that would benefit greatly from image examples. I just think that since we have a "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example." rule for code, we could have some similar way of explaining to people that e.g. image-processing question should most of the time contain image. I'm not saying all of them but now it seems like 5% of them do.

Comment: We do.  If you need the image sample in order to answer the question then the question does lack a Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable example.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20772893/how-to-detect-a-christmas-tree

Here's one of the interesting image-processing questions. It's not a code-related issue it's a question regarding an overall approach to solving the problem. No example is provided because no example exists. However, the author did provide samples and without them, the question wouldn't have been as useful for the community.

Not trying to argue, because I'm not experienced enough to make my point - just trying to paint the whole picture. I'll delete the question if it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @m3h0w the question makes sense but as Nathan says, we only have to provide a comment to the OP asking for such images and should they not provide them, the question will be downvoted and/or closed. _That_ mechanism is already in place. We get many of questions that ask a question regarding code and yet fail to post their code. If they do, we advise as a comment and should the OP show no interest in enhancing their question it get's closed and/or eventually deleted unless someone provides a well educated guess (answer that gets upvoted)

Comment: @Bugs I get that mechanism and it sure does its job but I think a pop-up window mentioning to users under certain reputation threshold that are selecting image-processing-related tag to remember about including image samples might greatly improve the quality of the image-processing questions. I just think that right now there is a huge disproportion in that area.

Comment: @m3h0w I wish it was as simple as that. Each tag has it's own issues and new users often fail to provide a proper MCVE. At least we have the facility to action these with downvotes and/or/ flagging and/or comments.

Answer (score 9):

## Nay.

Don't implement a "Image embedded" requirement. There's no way to reliably tell if a question should have an image.

Just close'm as *"no MCVE"* (*"Off-topic"* -> *"Questions seeking debugging help ..."*)

Comment: I don't think a requirement is a good solution. Wasn't sure what is but I did mention a pop-up helping inexperienced users that are choosing image-processing-related tags.

Comment: Not all questions in any specific tag require an image to be uploaded.
You could add it as a suggestion to the tag wiki, but I wouldn't do more than that.